# How to configure a conceptronic (C100S8) switch for Maas?

Tags: networking, server, maas, dhcp

I thought I had an issue with network configuration, but it turns out I didn't ([previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581299/maas-configuration-with-two-network-interfaces)). The problem is with my switch. As stated in [Maas 1.5 doc](http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs1.5/install.html#configure-switches-on-the-network) there are some issues with STP on certain switches. In the case of a Cisco switch it suggests enabling Portfast, but I can't find anything like that for Conceptronic Switch C100S8.

My question:
<s>Does anyone know how to achieve the equivalent of Portfast on a
Conceptronic Switch?</s> (I sent an email to the manufacture and they said it is a dump switch and there is no way to override the protocol.)

Comment: I maintain the question in case someone has the same difficulty with a identical switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the seller, Conceptronic, and they said this specific device is a dump switch and cannot have the protocol changed or tweaked.